# VBA Excel word search and copying formulas

Tags: vba, excel, search, excel-formula

I'm searching for a VBA macro for Excel, which can detect the word "mean", in column A. After this it would copy the yellow row with the formula in C to J.
The formula counts the average from one row after the last "mean" to the next =AVERAGE (C1323:C1437)

after every sixth mean there also needs to be Area and 150 copyied two rows after mean and I and J Need to be changed. Consequently I and J would refer to the cell A1441 in this case (=G1439/C1439*$A$1441) till the end of the file.

[image: Excel example]

I'm not quite sure if it's easy or not but I'm totally overchallenged. I would be very thankful for help.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
' Tastenkombination: Strg+q

   strSearchWord = "Mean"
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), strSearchWord)
Y = 2
For x = i To 0
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strSuchWort, Range("A:A"), 0)
     Range("C" & i).Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
      ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-147]C:R[-1]C)"  ' that's still wrong, should be something like i-y?
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C" & i:"J" & i), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("CY:JY").Select
i = Y

'for each fifth i
 'Range("A" & i + 3).Select
  '  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-6]*R2159C1"

Next x

End Sub
```

it's still wrong, but my first draft.

@stucharo the Area correction is difficult to describe I've added a better Picture with formulas. I hpe that now it's understandable[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your line `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-147]C:R[-1]C)"` needs to change the number of rows betwen means each time then you'll need to add a variable as you comment suggests.  Also, just writing the string to the cells value (`ActiveCell.Value`) means that you will see it written as a formaula when you click the cell in the workbook (and it'll highlight the range etc.).  You could try replacing it with:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=AVERAGE(R[" & i - Y & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

although since I can't see the first row of your sheet I'm not certain that'll give you the correct range of rows each time.

If your row number is likely to change and you are copying over the same number of columns each time then it might also be just as easy to write the formula directly to cells within a loop, rather than explicitly copying it.

Adding text after every 6th "mean" would require you to keep count of how many means had passed so far.  This can be done by incrememnting a counter variable and using the `Mod` operator will tell you the remainder after a division.  Therefor `numberOfMeans Mod 6` will give you the remainder when divided by 6 and when this equals zero you know you have a multiple of 6. 
 I've tried to capture all this into the code below.....

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2
Dim endrow As Integer
endrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).row

Dim lastMeanRow As Integer
lastMeanRow = startRow - 1
Dim areaRow as Integer
areaRow = lastMeanRow + 3
Dim meanCounter As Integer
meanCounter = 0

Dim avgColHeight As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer

'Check each row in the sheet
For row = startRow To endrow
    'Cols i and j in every row need to be modified
    For col = 9 To 10
        Cells(row, col).Value = "=RC[-2]/RC[-6]*R" & areaRow & "C1"
    Next col

    'If column 1 of that row contains "mean" then
    If Cells(row, 1).Value = "mean" Then

        'Calculate the column height to average over....
        avgColHeight = row - lastMeanRow - 1
        '...and loop through each of the columns....
        '(including i and j to add average)
        For col = 3 To 10
            '....inserting the averaging formula.
            Cells(row, col).Value = "=AVERAGE(R[-" & avgColHeight & "]C:R[-1]C)"
        Next col

        'Then increment the counter to keep track of the number of means
        meanCounter = meanCounter + 1
        'If the number of means is a multiple of 6 then
        If (meanCounter Mod 6 = 0) Then
            'insert the "Area" and "150" strings
            Cells(row + 2, 1).Value = "Area"
            Cells(row + 3, 1).Value = "150"
            areaRow = row + 3
        End If

        'Finally change the lastMeanRow to the mean row we have just processed.
        lastMeanRow = row

    End If
'Do it again until we reach the end of the data
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I also noticed your point on the value of area changing periodically.  Writing this programatically, as above, will aloow you to add some logic over the value of "Area" and when it changes.

Comment: thank you a lot, It works really good for the means. Copying of area and 150 works also at the right Point. One Problem is not completely solved and i do not unerstand where it is implemented and how the mistake evolves. row I and J between the means, in the raw data are supposed to be =G6899/C6899*$A$"value of cell where 150 is copied", thank you

Comment: @Nathalie I don't quite follow, should I and J be the same in each row or is I = G / C and J = H / D?  Should the 150 cell used be above or below the current row?

Comment: I've added a Picture to describe the Problem. the used cells for area need to be below., after inserting area.  whereas mean is supposed to Count the cells above (correctly in the script)

Comment: @Nathalie I think I understand now, I've modified the code a little, it will run a bit slower because you now need to update each row (to change the area cell in cols I and J).  You'll also need to have a value in for the first area before you start.

Comment: almost :-) I and J only change after area is inserted, now they change after every mean. so I suppose there should be a counter after If (meanCounter Mod 6 = 0) Then for a variable like lastmeanrow. Tried it. but couldn't implement it.It doesn't matter that its slower, so far it's great,Thank you

Comment: @Nathalie my bad, i've just added a variable to hold that row number that is then changed inside the `If (meanCounter Mod 6 = 0)` as you suggested :)

Comment: Thank you, works now after adding plus 3 rows down to the arearow. Looks ugly now. But works great!!! Thank you so much. Saved me days of working.     For col = 9 To 10
        areaRow = areaRow + 3
        Cells(row, col).Value = "=RC[-2]/RC[-6]*R" & areaRow & "C1"
        areaRow = areaRow - 3
    Next col

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84934/discussion-between-stucharo-and-nathalie).

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a long list of data and want to automate the creation of the rows and formulas you describe.

It is possible write VBA to scan through the data and modify the formulas etc but first I would question if this is the best approach to give you what you need.

Excel has a feature called "pivot tables" which essentially allows you to summerise data in a list.

for instance if the list had one row for each city in the world and gave the population in the city, and a column gave which country it was in.  A pivot table could be used to create the average population for a country of the countries cities. I suspect you are doing this sort of thing.

If you don't know about pivot tables you should find out about them.  See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-yuYNgsHAk)

In your case your mean row is summeriseing data in the rows above it.  To use pivot tables you would have to have a column that defined which group each row is in.  You pivot table would sue this column as a row summary and you would then create the average for all the other column.

@Nathalie.  It's hard to help without knowing more.  eg Is the data delivered with the mean text already inserted.   It looks like column A has a number the represent the row number within the group (and this could be used by a formula to create the "Group Name" column you need for pivot tables.

You can get the pivot tables to do the area adjustment by:

1. Creating a new set of columns which contains formulas that cause the values in columns C to J to be copied except for when it is the 6th set of data in which case you adjust the values in C to J accordingly).

   2. You probably need to introduce columns that:
   3. A. give the "group name"
      B. give a count of which group it is in so every 6th you can do the adjustment you need.

4 by using pivot tables and basic techniques you will find it easie rot update the refresh the data, should you need to.

Comment: thank you, good idea. But the value of Area changes periodically and Needs to be changeble, so it would not work in this case.

Comment: @Nathalie, did you use a pivot table to create the means? or did you mean to put your comment under the  other answer?
 My gut feeling is that you could probably do what you need with pivot tables, but as your explanation of the problem is limited, I can't help more.  There would be ways of allowing the value of area to change I am sure.

Comment: no the comment is directed at you. It is helpful. I tried it. One part of the Problem is solvable. but it's not fully working. Area is changing periodically and in some cases after checking the values even sometimes changed manually. Consequently formulas in I and J need to be adapted to...